# getting "missing script: serve" when I am running npm run serve

Tags: laravel

I'm receiving this error when I am trying run" npm run serve" in my laravel project
her it is my package.json file

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
      
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "core-js": "^2.6.5",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^0.10.0np",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22"
    }
}



The error is

npm ERR! missing script: serve

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Natty\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-24T01_39_21_234Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You don't have a `serve` entry in the `scripts` section.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear here. You should define `serve` script to be able to run it.